# Dehn surgery on handlebody

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds, at.algebraic-topology

Assume $V$ is a handlebody and $C$ be a simple closed curve contained in the interior of $V$. 
As Sam said, there exists some simple closed curve such that every dehn surgery along it produces a handlebody. So I assume $C$ can not be isotopic to a simple closed curve in $\partial V$.

Obviously, trivial dehn surgery along $C$ produces a handlebody. So My question is:

Is there a different dehn surgery along $C$ which produces a handlebody?

Can we classify all the dehn surgery along $C$ which produce handlebodies?

Comment: With respect, the third line is unclear and needs to be rewritten.  Also, it would help to have a definition of unknotted. 

Comment: I can point out that if $C$ is a core curve (meets some essential disk in a single point and is also isotopic into the boundary) then _every_ Dehn filling on $C$ gives a handlebody. 

Comment: @Sam. Thank you for your advice. I have rewritten it.

Comment: @Yanqing - There are many pairs $(V, C)$ where we may embed $V$ into three-space and $V$ is a standard handlebody, $C$ is an unknot in three-space, and yet $C$ is very complicated inside of $V$.  So, with your current definition, I see no hope for a reasonable answer to your question.  That said, you might be interested in the ideas of "cosmetic Dehn surgery" and "Property R".  best 

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's an extensive literature on this and more general questions.

First, let's consider a more precise formulation of the question. 
Let $H$ be a handlebody, and let $K\subset H$ be a knot. Let's
assume that $\partial H \subset H-K$ is incompressible. Otherwise,
$H=H_0 \natural H_1$ the boundary connect sum of two handlebodies,
such that $K\subset H_0$, and $\partial H_0 \subset H_0-K$ is
incompressible. Then a surgery on $K$ makes $H$ a handlebody if
and only if the corresponding surgery makes $H_0$ a handlebody. 
Thus, one may reduce to considering the case that $K$ is *diskbusting*.

With this reformulation of the question, the case that $K$ is
a core curve corresponds to when $H$ is a solid torus, and $K$ is
a core curve (since this is the only case in which a core curve is
diskbusting). So assume that $K$ is not a core curve. If $K$
is isotopic into $\partial H$, then there are infinitely many surgeries
which yield $H$. In this case, there is an annulus going between the
knot and $\partial H$. The surgery slopes which intersect the annulus
slope once give back $H$. Surgery along the annular slope gives
a manifold containing an incompressible surface, by Jaco's lemma. 
If the intersection with the annulus slope is $>1$, then the manifold
has incompressible boundary by Theorem 2.4.3 of the [cyclic surgery paper](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=881270).

A [result of Wu](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1167169) implies that for knots $K$ which
are not isotopic into the boundary, the distance between boundary-reducible
surgeries is at most one, and therefore there are at most two non-trivial
surgeries which may yield a handlebody.

In the case that $H$ is a solid torus, it was proved by [Berge](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1093862)
and [Gabai](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=991095) that $K$ must be a 1-bridge braid, and a complete description
was given. There is a famous example (the Berge link) which yields 3 solid torus surgeries,
which shows that Wu's estimate is sharp (there is a 3-fold symmetry permuting
the slopes).

Wu has [further results](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1401956) on the case of 1-bridge knots in handlebodies. 
**Added:** [Frigerio, Martelli and Petronio](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2032111) show that there are 1-bridge
knots in handlebodies with three handlebody fillings (including the trivial one),
generalizing the example of the Berge link to higher genus boundary, and showing
that Wu's theorem is sharp in general. It seems to be an open question whether
all such examples are 1-bridge (see discussion in [another of Wu's papers](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1202395)).

Comment: In a joint paper with Martelli and Petronio (Dehn filling of cusped hyperbolic 3-manifolds with geodesic boundary, J. Diff. Geom. 64 (2003), 425-456), for every g>1 we gave examples of knots in the genus-g handlebody with the following properties: the complement of each such knot is hyperbolic (with one cusp and a geodesic boundary component), so in particular each such knot is not isotopic to the boundary of the handlebody; each of them has exactly three surgeries giving back the handlebody. Every knot in our family is 1-bridge.

Comment: Thanks for the reference Roberto, sorry for overlooking your result! 

Comment: @Agol. In the last second paragraph, $H$ should be a handlebody ? 

Comment:  
With this reformulation of the question, the case that K is a core curve corresponds to when H is a solid torus, and K is a core curve. 

Are two $K$ same above?   

Comment: @ yangqing yes and yes. 

Comment: @Agol: R. Sean Bowman constructed knots in a genus 2 handle body that have a non-trivial handle body filling but are not 1-bridge. His results are here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.1959v1.pdf. 